# MEAN stack env in Android

Tags: android, mean-stack, devops, devtools

I have a OnePlus7pro and Im working in a mean stack project in my laptop, but some times I have free time with my phone and I like to add some lines, test, and push  to my project?

So then the question comes to me?

Q. Is  possible to setup ,run, test and push a MEAN project running in Android 10?

Any ideas?

Comment: webview maybe could be a client for your mean project

Comment: I'm thinking more like the base of Android is Unix and with root is easy to install node and npm , but what about a good ide I have the premium bm veduisn